# Cannot send the follow up emails and email reminders in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I have installed this extension in my website Abandoned cart / Follow up emails. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/abandoned-cart-follow-up-emails-1.html
But I can not able to send the emails to customers about reminders.
I have changed the configuration settings.Can anyone please suggest me.

Comment: If it is paid extension, contact the  extension devolopers.

Comment: No it is free extension

Comment: I cannot send the emails and I could not create a template with this extension.

Comment: please update the question the extensions link. and is normal emails are working ?

Comment: This is the extension link http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/web4pro_Abandonedcart

Comment: the link is not working

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/abandoned-cart-follow-up-emails-1.html try this

Comment: send an email to the extension devolopers : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/developer/WEB4PRO

Comment: It is not working for you

Comment: i did't used this extension.

Comment: Can you please use it and check it and suggest me.

Comment: sorry, bit busy now, i will check later....

Comment: Can you please suggest me any free extension are there for Follow up Email.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-follow-up-email-extensions-for-magento

Comment: Did you check transaction mail configure or not

Comment: No.Please suggest me.How to check??